# create csv file with information on "*active* computer usage" (purpose: to monitor possible relation to neck and shoulder pain)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, lubuntu

So I suffer from neck and shoulder pain, and I have written a dmenu-based script where I can log my pain level each day in an easy, menu-based way.

Of course, there is a relationship with my time spent in front of the compuer and the pain.  I would like to meaure the relationship more precisly, so I can load my measurement of pain and my computertime into R and look at correlations and the like.

But how do I get a measure of *active* computertime? I can get something like uptime, bt that's way too inaccurate - I'm looking for some way of measuring the time where I'm activley using the keyboard, or something like that: I have the worktimer Workrave installed, and it seems pretty good at detecting mouse and keyboard input so as to judge wether I am "working" - and the timer should be counting - and wether it's "idle" - and the timer stops. This is basically what I'm looking for.

something like procinfo might be it, from the man page:

> user:  The amount of time spent  running jobs in user space.
>
> nice:  The  amount of time spent running niced jobs in user space.
>
> system: The amount of time spent  running in  kernel space.  Note: the
> time spent servicing interrupts is not counted  by the kernel (and
> noth‐ ing that procinfo  can  do  about it).
>
> idle:  The  amount  of  time spent doing nothing.
>
> uptime: The time that the system has been up. The above four should
> more or less add up to this one.

So this might be it, but I'm not really sure what the "idle" type is - "the amount of time doing nothing" - is that in terms of cpu/ram usage, I'm guessing it is - and if that's the case, this is not useful for this purpose. And if not that program, what else could be used?

I'm on a Lubuntu 20.04 machine.